# How to specific with file name and upload files

Tags: php

I want to upload images to specific folder and also give particular name

Here is my PHP code to upload files

index.php

```
   <div class="image_form">
   <form action="upload.php" method="post">
   Image1: <input name="userfile" type="file" /> <br />

   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />               <br />
   </form>       
   </div>
```

and my upload.php file coding is

```
  $path = "images_db/";

if(isset($_POST))
    {
    $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

    if(strlen($name))
    {

    $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name))
       echo "Success!";
      else
       echo "Failed";
    }
    }
```

I want to add one new feature in `index.php` file to show two options like
option 1 - for Customer
option 2- for dealer

I have two folders such as customer and dealer if I click option 1 then images should be stored in option 1 and if I click option 2 then images should be stored in other folder.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hidden data type to pass your needed value from index file and change file name according to that value ,  by doing so u can what u want,

index.php

```
  <div class="image_form">
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input name="option(1 or 2 as per ur need)"  type="hidden" />//hidden variable
       Image1: <input name="userfile" type="file" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />         <br />
   </form>       
 </div>
```

your upload.php file should contain

```
     $path = "images_db/";

       if(isset($_POST))
         {
              $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
              $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

              $option=$_POST['option']; 

        if(strlen($name))
         {

         $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.'/'.$option.$name))
           echo "Success!";
         else
           echo "Failed";
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag should look like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```